# change language based on resx value?

Tags: c#

I have two resx file with resource key and its value how to access value of that resx file       so     that i  can change language

```
string resourceFile = "~/App_LocalResources/site.Master.Germany.resx";
string filePath = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString();
ResourceManager resourceManager = 
      ResourceManager.CreateFileBasedResourceManager(resourceFile,filePath,null);
string resourceValue = resourceManager.GetString(resourceFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string resourceValue = resourceManager.GetString(resourceFile);
```

The parameter of `resourceManager.GetString(string key)` should be the resource's key not be the resourcefile .